# Как работает программа Recuva(HDD)?

Tags: windows

Я хотел использовать удаление файлов программой [Recuva](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recuva). Но как я прочитал, она просто **перезаписывает на их место рандомные числа**, а мне она нужна была для очищения места. Правильно ли я понимаю, что это место не почистить?

Comment: А почистить диск, это что, тряпочкой протереть? если Вам просто менста не хватает - удяйте файлы любым доступным способом (даже через проводник) и не забудьте почистить корзину. Программы вида recuva затирают файлы на диске, так как даже после удаления файла его ещё можно восстановить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Нет, неправильно.

Дело в том, что типичная процедура удаления во многих файловых системах всего лишь "теряет файл" и помечает больше не занятое им место, как свободное, то есть, место всё-таки освобождается.

**Потому что эта процедура не уничтожает данные, которые в файле находились.** Просто штатным способом их больше не найти. Они всё ещё на диске, но гарантий, что они там и останутся, больше нет.

Но кто-нибудь, слоняясь по жёсткому диску на самых низких уровнях, на которых диск представляет собой просто большой блоб бинарных данных, **может на эти данные наткнуться**.

Упомянутая Recuva и другие программные продукты для "безопасного удаления файлов" (secure erase) усложняют восстановление данных из удаляемых файлов, записав поверх их старого содержимого случайную информацию.

Впрочем, из-за погрешностей в работе жёстких магнитных дисков даже после одного прохода "случайной замазкой" информацию ещё может быть возможно восстановить. Правда, для этого уже может потребоваться специальное оборудование. Поэтому по файлам, которые вы не хотели бы раскрывать, стоит пройтись этой "случайной замазкой" несколько (возможно, много) раз.

---

**Но это всё неважно, если вы удаляете файл, в котором никаких секретных данных нет.**

**Такие просто удаляйте штатным способом. Занимаемое ими место освободится.**

Comment: @антонсорокин нас [довольно много в Питере](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3792/%D0%92%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-stack-overflow-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5).